# Где Word хранит свои картинки?

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, office, office-interop

В общем, есть много Word'ов, которые я обрабатываю через `interop` и пытаюсь вытянуть картинки, что бы их сохранить отдельно.

До сего момента я просто брал `InlineShapes` и сохранял их.

Однако, попался хитрый Word, где кол-во `InlineShapes`=0 и есть просто обычный Shape, который имеет Id=17(Т.е текстовый) и в него вписана картинка.

Я копался в свойствах этого Shape, но не нашел каких-либо свойств в которых могла бы хранится картинка.

Как я могу достать картинку из этого Shape и сохранить ее?

Да, есть вариант конвертировать все в docx, а потом открыть zip'ом и все такое..., но это крайний случай.

P.S Тег VBA так как работа с interop+- похожа на VBA=> VBAшное решение на 99% мне подойдет.

Comment: Приложите пример документа

Comment: @АндрейNOP Сюда залил https://ufile.io/cin1v8gw

Answer (score 1):

Собственно у вас получается, что inlineShape вставлен в Shape. Если преобразовать Shape в InlineShape, то получим рисунок с рамкой, а это не совсем то, что нужно.

Есть вариант с использованием OpenXML

Надо поставить референс на NugetPackage DocumentFormat.OpenXml

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
```

Далее мы проходим по всем внедренным изображениям и сохраняем

```
string document = @"D:\ttt.docx";
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument =
                WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, false))
            {
                var imageParts = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.ImageParts;
                foreach (var imagePart in imageParts)
                {
                    var uri = imagePart.Uri;
                    var filename = uri.ToString().Split('/').Last();
                    var stream = wordprocessingDocument.Package.GetPart(uri).GetStream();

                    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(stream);
                    b.Save(@"D:\" + filename);
                }
            }
```

В данном способе мы сохраняем любые внедренные изображения независимо от места внедрения.

Comment: А никак нельзя только то, что нужно вычленить из Shape?

Comment: внутри Shape лежит рисунок и он не inline. В фигуру внедрен объект, который находится в графическом слое документа, а inlineShapes находится в текстовом слое документа.